# Native DLNA client for "Xbox Series X"

Tags: xbox-series-x-series-s

When I search the web for *+xbox +dlna* I get lots of hits, but mostly Xbox One. I wish to stream from latest Ubuntu (Raspberry) to Xbox Series X with DLNA. Is there a native client?

I know that VLC, Kodi and Plex exists. But those are 3rd party solutions.

Comment: This is somewhat a recommendation question. Are you looking for a client that would already be on the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft, their Media Player application will play files from USB devices or a DLNA media server.

[Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/media-player/9vwgnh0vbzl2#activetab=pivot:overviewtab) link.

Comment: What is the media player on the Xbox called? Just "Media Player"? Also, do you have any supporting links that may show how to set this up?

Comment: "Play media from your USB device or DLNA media server on your Xbox One." No instructions that I can see but I am not near an xbox to try installing it at the moment. It is that same app that you would used if you had purchased a movie from the microsoft store. Despite the quote above, this is available for series x/s as well.

Comment: Link to the application: "https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/media-player/9vwgnh0vbzl2#activetab=pivot:overviewtab". On the xbox store (one or series x/s) it should be easy to find using the search function. You still have to download it, it's not on the xbox out of the box. Maybe you don't count it as 'native' but it is not third party.